# New HIRECLICK Widget Coding for Subsplash

Tags: widget

I am trying to embed a widget piece of coding from New HIRECLICK into my Subsplash website platform, but it will not show. Is this coding that the website provided me correct? I tested it on another platform and it worked, so if anyone has specific knowledge with how to embed code on Subsplash, please help!

Here is the code:

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Here is the code: <script src="https://hireclick.com/Integrations/Website/WebsiteJobListings.js" defer></script><div id="hireclickWidgetTopLevel" data-id="511BC5B0-DD00-4BAD-BFF9-212A7DBD4120"></div>